# Javafx: Load image via css from outside jar

Tags: java, css, image, jar, javafx

I am trying to load an image file as a background for  my javafx application.

Filestructure:

```
+F:/Repositories/DungeonCraft
|-+resources
| |-+images
| | |-splash.png
| |
| |-+styles
|   |-style.css
| 
|-application.jar
```

style.css:

```
.root {
    -fx-background-color: rgb(1,1,1);
    -fx-background-image: url("../images/splash.png");
    -fx-background-repeat: stretch;
    -fx-background-size: contain;
    -fx-background-position: center center;
}
```

I have no trouble loading style.css. The program runs and displays the styles correctly, but the image is not loaded. I get the following error in console:

```
Jul 13, 2015 2:54:31 AM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager getCachedImage
WARNING: Error loading image: file:/F:/Repositories/DungeonCraft/resources/images/splash.png
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What do you want to state when your question heading says, "from outside jar"?

Comment: And dos that file exist at this location?  `F:/Repositories/DungeonCraft/resources/images/splash.png`

Comment: I have already answered this post myself, but the interface wont let me accept my answer yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this was a dumb mistake on my part.
The image file had been corrupted and after inserting a new one the code works like a charm.

regards :)